# Adding the values of the edittext in android

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have five edittext fields in which i ll be entering the amount values and one seperate field to display the total amount. Say, I enter 2000 in the first field and click on the second field, the 2000 will be set in the total field. The again if I enter 1500 in the second field, the total of first and second should be set to the total field, that is 3500. Likewise all the five fields total i need to set on the focus change.

```
int total = 0;
int val = 0;

monthly_rent_et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
              System.out.println("Calc "+Integer.valueOf(monthly_rent_et.getText().toString()));
              val = val + total+Integer.valueOf(monthly_rent_et.getText().toString());
              total_et.setText(String.valueOf(val));
            }
        }
     });
    water_et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
              System.out.println("Calc "+Integer.valueOf(water_et.getText().toString()));
              val = val + total+Integer.valueOf(water_et.getText().toString());
              total_et.setText(String.valueOf(val));
            }
        }
     });
```

this code is getting me the answer but while editting the amount, both the old and the edited value is getting added. How to fix this? Is there any better way to do this calculation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array to contain all five `editTexts` to reduce your code and do calculations like this:

```
EditText[] editTexts;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // After setting contentView and other initialisations
    editTexts = new EditText[] {monthly_rent_et, water_et, ....};
    for (int i=0 ; i<editTexts.length ; i++) {
        editTexts[i].setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    }
}

private View.OnFocusChangeListener mFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i=0 ; i<editTexts.length ; i++) {
            try {
                total += Integer.valueOf(editTexts[i].getText().toString());
            } catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        total_et.setText(total + "");
    }
};
```

Comment: I'm getting java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "" error

Comment: @NivedhaS It was because editText might be empty.. I have added exception handling.. try the updated Code again.

Comment: is it possible to calculate percentage and add to the total of this value?

Comment: I have posted a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30449238/calculating-percentages-value-of-edittext-in-android. Can u pls go through n find a solution. @Asif Mujteba

Answer (score 0):

Instead the adding the current value to the existing total value, get values values from all the `EditText`'s and then set the total to the total `EditText`.
For example:

```
  water_et.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (!hasFocus) {
              int final =0;
              final+=getValue(et1.getText().toString()); //Add the first edittext value
              final+=getValue(et2.getText().toString()); //Add the second edittext value
              final+=getValue(et3.getText().toString()); //Add the third edittext value
              final+=getValue(et4.getText().toString()); //Add the forth edittext value
              final+=getValue(et5.getText().toString()); //Add the fifth edittext value

              total_et.setText(String.valueOf(final));
            }
        }
     });

   public int getValue(String text)){
      if(TextUtils.isEmpty(text){
          return 0;
       }
     return Integer.valueOf(text);
}
```

Comment: whether i have to repeat this in all the five edittext onfocusChange?

Comment: this will result in exception. Put if condition in each of 5 et's and check et.getText().length>0.

Comment: yes, simple you can have single method with the logic for calculating the sum and call the that method from all the onFocusChange() methods.

Comment: @NivedhaS just implement OnFocusChangeListener on your activity and then integrate the code in the overridden function

Comment: yes @NivedhaS implementing the onFocusChangeListener to activity is better option.

Answer (score 0):

```
Edittext1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Total.setText(Edittext1.getText().toString());        
    }
});
Edittext2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
         Total.setText(Edittext1.getText().toString() + Edittext2.getText().toString());
    }
});
```

Like Wise you can change for your code

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be something like this

```
public class CalculatorActivity extends Activity implements  View.OnFocusChangeListener{
    private EditText et1;
    private EditText et2;
    private EditText et3;
    private EditText et4;
    private EditText et5;
    private EditText resultet;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_calculator);
        et1 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et1);
        et2 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et2);
        et3 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et3);
        et4 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et4);
        et5 =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.et5);
        resultet = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.resultet);

        et1.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et2.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et3.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et4.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);
        et5.setOnFocusChangeListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
        if(!b) {
            int sum = sumAllEditTextValues();
            resultet.setText(sum);
        }
    }
    int sumAllEditTextValues(){
        int result =0;
        result+=parseLieniant(et1.getText().toString());
        result+=parseLieniant(et2.getText().toString());
        result+=parseLieniant(et3.getText().toString());
        result+=parseLieniant(et4.getText().toString());
        result+=parseLieniant(et5.getText().toString());
        return 0;
    }
    private int parseLieniant(String s ){
        int result = 0;
        try{
            result =  Integer.parseInt(s);
        }catch(Exception e){

        }
        return result;
    }
}
```