# Calculating percentages value of edittext in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have got the code to add the values of multiple `edittext` fields and display the total in one field. Now I need to include the percentage calculation of two more `edittext` fields along with the total value.

```
editTexts = new EditText[] {monthly_rent_et, water_et,eb_et,sewage_et,maint_et,others_et,sec_deposit_et};
    for (int i=0 ; i<editTexts.length ; i++) {
        editTexts[i].setOnFocusChangeListener(mFocusChangeListener);
    }

private View.OnFocusChangeListener mFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        int total = 0;
        for (int i=0 ; i<editTexts.length-1 ; i++) {

            try {
                total += Integer.valueOf(editTexts[i].getText().toString());
            }
            catch(Exception e) {}
        }
        total_et.setText(total + "");

    }
};
```

Now I need to calculate the service tax percentage (monthly rent value*service tax value)/100 and and this to total. Also penalty percentage as same like service tax. Service tax and penalty are two more `edittext`  fields and the monthly rent is already included in the above code. How can I get this?

Comment: You could have a edit text and a textview.. calculate and display the  service tax percentage in the textview as the user is givin the input( with a common function). same goes for all your values and one extra textview for the total..hope its not confusin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose `service_tax_et` and `penalty_et` are new `editTexts`, don't add them to the array instead set `focusChangeListener` on them manually and then try like this:

```
private View.OnFocusChangeListener mFocusChangeListener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    float total = 0;
    for (int i=0 ; i<editTexts.length-1 ; i++) {
        try {
            total += Integer.valueOf(editTexts[i].getText().toString());
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    }

    try {
        float service_tax_perc = (Integer.valueOf(monthly_rent_et.getText().toString()) + Integer.valueOf(service_tax_et.getText().toString())) / 100;
        total += service_tax_perc;
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    try {
        float penalty_perc = (Integer.valueOf(monthly_rent_et.getText().toString()) + Integer.valueOf(penalty_et.getText().toString())) / 100;
        total += penalty_perc;
    } catch (Exception e) {}

    total_et.setText(total + "");
}};
```